# ХОрошая литература по оптимизации Java программ

Tags: оптимизация, java

Здравствуйте. Посоветуйте пожалуйста что можно полезного почитать по оптимизации уже существующих java-программ (настройки jvm и тд и тп), а также по написанию наиболее оптимизированного java-кода с нуля, оптимизация процессорного времени, потребления памяти и тд. Хочу почитать что-то именно касаемо java и jvm а не фундаментальные понятия алгоритмов и подобного. Например - какие структуры данных в каких ситуациях нужно использовать для большей эффективности. Что-то вроде паттернов по оптимизации, если такое высказывание корректно)) Спасибо

Comment: можно прочитать 100500 умных книг где авторы будут давать свои рекомендации по поводу улучшения перфоманса. давать много умных фактов (к сожалению сложно запоминающихся). Но все меняется, и бывает так, что то что оптимально работало в одной версии, в другой будет работать по другому. 
пожалуй более универсальным решением будет научится пользоватся профайлером, научится находить проблемные секции, анализировать собственный код.  
в принцыпе я не отвергаю того что читать литературу полезно но теория без практики - ничто

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Всё что касается оптимизации производительности вообще касается и Java + надо понимать, как работает компьютер, как работает физическая оперативная память, как работает процессор и кэш, знать как работают блокировки, атомарные операции и т.п., понимать как устроена сама JVM, как работает JIT (Just-In-Time Compiller) и как работает GC. Я боюсь что нет книги, способной охватить всё это разом.

По общим алгоритмам ясное дело книг хватает.

По работе железа тут вам поможет изучение (хотя бы беглое ассемблера). По работе и оптимизации по памяти есть книга [Криса Касперски "Техника оптимизации программ. Эффективное использование памяти"](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1418882/) - содержит весьма полезные сведения о работе памяти.

Про JIT скорее всего просто напросто нет книг, так что копайте через гугл, чтобы понять.

Про GC есть полно книг по теории сборки мусора и менеджменту ресурсов. Про именно GC из Java есть полно статей, на том же хабре.

Ко всему этому надо добавить всякие стандартные вещи, такие как [Java SE Performance at a Glance](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/performance.jsp),  [Java Performance Tuning](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/), [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601/ref=pd_sim_b_2).

Была ещё такая книжка [Горький вкус Java](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1425895/). Она устарела по технологиям, но там много важный и полезных идей, в том числе и по перфомансу. Брать оттуда рашения напрямую нельзя, но там совершенно точно определяется, на чём люди горят и как исправлять.

Вообще, производительность Java-приложений складывается из множества аспектов. Многие из них описываются в [википедии](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_performance).

Comment: +1, хабр полезно проверять регулярно, - там часто проскакивают статьи на тему перфоманс java. при чем разного уровня сложности

Answer (score 0):

"Рефакторинг. Улучшение существующего кода", Мартин Фаулер
Продается на [ozon'e](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1308678/)

Comment: Но ведь это не по перфомансу вовсе